# Using htaccess to change the name of a folder

Tags: .htaccess

I know there's a simple answer to this but I can't find a specific solution to this problem. I have seen how to use htaccess to mask a folder as the root, so domain.com/folder appears as domain.com in a browser. But what should I do if I want domain.com/folder to appear as domain.com/differentfolder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^differentfolder(/.*)?$ /folder$1 [L,NC]
```